# How to keep View state inside GridView Adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, android-view, baseadapter

I'm trying to make gallery of pictures from different rooms/places. Those are tagged by **id** and I want to show them on different Grids (same GridView but I'm just changing dataset and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`). Also single item has `CheckBox` which user can check (but only one per grid) and then he can go to next "page" with new data set. But at the next page same `CheckBox` is already checked or while pressing "previous" it's not checked or both are checked or other messed up situations. I've tried lots of solutions: keeping table of those check boxes, keeping their ID's, keeping previously checked `CheckBox` and that's not all but nothing works.

Here's my code:
**Adapter:**

```
public class GalleryGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<PhotosPOJO> galleryList;
    private static String[] checkTab;
    private static int[] checkBoxNumberTab;
    //private static int[] selectedTab;
    //private static CheckBox prevSelected;
    private int roomNumber;


    public GalleryGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PhotosPOJO> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.galleryList = list;
        //prevSelected = null;
        checkTab = new String[12];
        checkBoxNumberTab = new int[12];
        //selectedTab = new int[12];
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            checkTab[i] = null;
            checkBoxNumberTab[i] = -1;
            //selectedTab[i] = NO_ID;
        }
    }

    public void setRoomNumber(int roomNumber) {
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return galleryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final String photo = galleryList.get(i).getAbsolutePath();

        if (view == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_gallery, null);
        }

        final PhotoView photoView = (PhotoView) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery_photo_view);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery_checkbox);
        final ImageView ivTrash = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery_iv_trash);

        checkBox.bringToFront();
        ivTrash.bringToFront();


        Glide.with(context)
                .load(photo)
                .into(photoView);

        ivTrash.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_restore_from_trash));



        for (int k = 0; k < viewGroup.getChildCount(); k++) {
            if (viewGroup.getChildAt(k) instanceof CheckBox) {
                ((CheckBox) viewGroup.getChildAt(k)).setChecked(false);
            }
        }

        if (checkBoxNumberTab[roomNumber] != -1) {
            ((CheckBox) viewGroup.getChildAt(checkBoxNumberTab[roomNumber]).findViewById(R.id.gallery_checkbox)).setChecked(true);
        }



        /*checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (prevSelected != null) {
                    prevSelected.setChecked(false);
                    ((CheckBox) view).setChecked(true);
                    prevSelected = (CheckBox) view;
                    checkTab[roomNumber] = photo;
                } else {
                    ((CheckBox) view).setChecked(true);
                    prevSelected = (CheckBox) view;
                }
            }
        });*/



        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (b) {
                    if (checkTab[roomNumber] != null) {
                        //prevSelected.setChecked(false);
                        for (int k = 0; k < viewGroup.getChildCount(); k++) {
                            if (compoundButton == viewGroup.getChildAt(k)) {
                                checkBoxNumberTab[roomNumber] = k;
                            }
                        }
                        compoundButton.setChecked(true);

                        //selectedTab[roomNumber] = compoundButton.getId();
                        //prevSelected = (CheckBox)compoundButton;
                        checkTab[roomNumber] = photo;
                    } else {
                        compoundButton.setChecked(true);
                        checkTab[roomNumber] = photo;
                        //selectedTab[roomNumber] = compoundButton.getId();
                        //prevSelected = (CheckBox)compoundButton;
                    }

                } else {
                    checkTab[roomNumber] = null;
                    checkBoxNumberTab[roomNumber] = -1;
                    //selectedTab[roomNumber] = NO_ID;
                    //prevSelected = null;
                }

            }
        });

        ivTrash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                galleryList.remove(i);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<PhotosPOJO> newPhotos) {
        this.galleryList = newPhotos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //public int[] getTabValue(int roomNumber) {
     //   return checkTab;
    //}
}
```

**Creating GridView:**

```
gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.galleryGridView);  // my GridView
        galleryAdapter = new GalleryGridAdapter(this, galleryList);
        galleryAdapter.setRoomNumber(roomNumber);
        gv.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
```

**Updating Grid:**

```
private void updateView() {
        galleryList = new ArrayList<>();
        galleryList = dbPhotos.getPhotosByRoom(roomNumber);
        galleryAdapter.setData(galleryList);
        galleryAdapter.setRoomNumber(roomNumber);
        Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, String.valueOf(roomNumber), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**Calling method:** (for update)

```
private void setListeners() {
       fabLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               if (roomNumber > 0) {
                   --roomNumber;
                   fabRight.show();
               }
               if (roomNumber == 0) {
                   fabLeft.hide();
               } else {
                   fabLeft.show();
               }

               updateView();
           }
       });
       fabRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               if (roomNumber < 11) {
                   ++roomNumber;
                   fabLeft.show();

               }
               if (roomNumber == 11) {
                   fabRight.hide();
               } else {
                   fabRight.show();
               }
               updateView();
           }
       });
   }
```

I'm stuck here. Maybe I'm missing something but I really do not know how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
 So I've resolved this by using `SharedPreferences`. I am saving `position` of `CheckBox` using prefs key `"RoomNumber" + roomNumber` and then I'm reading it depending on roomNumber. Thanks to `SharedPreferences` works even after app is closed.